# Sound plays in emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to find or convert sound files to use in my Android game that will play on both the emulator (which is rather easy to do) as well as a physical device (which appears to be harder to do).

My original sound effect was a .Wav file, 16 bit stereo and played just fine on both the emulator and testing device, but was 120Kb (which multiplied my file size by five, and I need two more sound effects!) and wasn't an appropriate sound for the game.

Any attempts make the file smaller (changing it to mono, using 8 bits instead of 16, converting it to an MP3, etc.) caused the sound to fail to be played on the physical device.

Is there any way to determine what problems the decoder has trying to read the sound files? The log files don't give any error messages during load times, and only says "sample *x* is not READY" when I try to play it.

Also, I'm using Android 1.5 and can't upgrade my physical device to a later version, so it's hard limit right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended format for Android sound files is `ogg`. Try using that.

Comment: It turns out that FFmpeg wasn't letting me convert Wave files to proper Vorbis-encoded .Ogg files, so I had to use a different program.

Answer (score 0):

Try streaming the audio for background and splashscreen (if you have one) and hard code Button sound.